# How to end recursive SQL query in Powershell 7.0

Tags: sql, powershell, for-loop, recursion

I need to explode Bills of Materials.
I have a single SQL table with PartRn(Primary Key), UsedOnRn. I only need to go down the tree of Bills Of Material. Which means I need to know what a part was made of.
The recursive query works in SSMS no issues.

The problem is when I write in Powershell to run a recursive query on all the values of PartRn the recursive loop would not end.

The idea was to display the Part_Number and Revision of corresponding of the parent part side-by-side with all the child parts in a csv file.

I have tried adding conditions to the query like UsedOnRn =! $partRn or limit the number of recursion but nothing works
*Edit --> Attached is the picture of intended result. It is from SSMS but I have labeled what things are
[image]

```
$server = "Server"
$database = "database"
$csvFilePath = "\\server\BOM\BOM_Master_1.csv"
$query = "SELECT Top 5 [PartRn],[PART_NUMBER],[NAME],[Revision] From [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngParts_Master_Aras]"
$initialResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $query
$Array1 = @()
$Array2 = @()

foreach ($item in $initialResult) {
$partRn = $item.PartRn
$revision = $item.Revision
$partNumber = $item.Part_Number
Write-host $partRn -ForegroundColor Yellow

# Add PartRn and Revision to Array#1
$Array1 += [PSCustomObject]@{
    PartRn     = $partRn
    Revision   = $revision
    PartNumber = $partNumber
}
$queryTable1 = "SELECT PartRn, Revision, PART_NUMBER FROM [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngParts_Master_Aras]"
$initialResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $queryTable1
$Array1 = @()
$Array2 = @()

foreach ($item in $initialResult) {
    $PartRn = $item.PartRn
    $Revision = $item.Revision
    $PartNumber = $item.PART_NUMBER
    # Add PartRn and Revision to Array#1
    $Array1 += [PSCustomObject]@{
        PartRn     = $PartRn
        Revision   = $Revision
        PartNumber = $PartNumber
    }

    $recursiveQuery = "
    WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT [Part_Number] AS PartRnBOM, UsedOnRn, PartRn, QtyPerAssy, Item, Remarks, 0 AS RecursionLevel
    FROM [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngBillsOfMaterial_Aras]
    WHERE UsedOnRn = '2'    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT bom.[Part_Number] AS PartRnBOM, bom.UsedOnRn, bom.PartRn, bom.QtyPerAssy, bom.Item, bom.Remarks, cte.RecursionLevel + 1
    FROM [NIMS_Eng].[dbo].[vEngBillsOfMaterial_Aras] AS bom
    JOIN RecursiveCTE AS cte ON bom.UsedOnRn = cte.PartRn
    Where cte.UsedOnRn = 2    )
    SELECT PartRnBOM, UsedOnRn, PartRn, QtyPerAssy, Item, Remarks
    FROM RecursiveCTE"
    $Array2 += Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database $Database -Query $recursiveQuery
    Write-host "Added in Array 2" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
    $combinedResult = $Array1 | ForEach-Object {
    $currentPartRn = $_.PartRn
    $matchingRows = $Array2 | Where-Object { $_.PartRn -eq $currentPartRn }
    foreach ($matchingRow in $matchingRows) {
        write-host $matchingRow.PartRnBOM -ForegroundColor Red
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PartRnBOM" -Value $matchingRow.PartRnBOM
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UsedOnRnBOM" -Value $matchingRow.UsedOnRn
        $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ItemBOM" -Value $matchingRow.Item
    }
    $_  
}
}
$combinedResult | Export-Csv -Path $csvFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Have you tried _not re-using variable names_ for your nested loop?

Comment: You could probably do this whole thing as one big SQL query. but it's not clear. Please give sample data and expected results.

Comment: I do not see any recursion in the code posted.  You should be able to take working code and convert line by line from SSMS to Powershell.  I've done it lots of times without issues.

Comment: @jdweng the recursive query is in the variable `$recursiveQuery`

Comment: Try adding to Invoke-SQL the option -AbortOnError